# How to copy an array in Julia 1.0

Tags: julia

My code is below.

```
V = ntuple(x -> zeros(5, 5), 2)    
V1 = rand(5,5)    
copy!(V[1], V1)
```

I would like to replace all the values in `V[1]` by `V1`. `copy!` works well in Julia 0.6.3. However, it doesn't work in Julia 1.0.1.

Error message: `MethodError: no method matching copy!(::Array{Float64,2}, ::Array{Float64,2})`

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I have not checked Julia 1.0.1, but `copy!(V[1], V1)` works under Julia 1.1. What problem do you have under Julia 1.0.1?

Comment: Seems `copy!` was [not defined](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/29173) between arrays before 1.1. `copyto!` works on 1.0, though.

Comment: @Mizzle are you getting `MethodError: no method matching copy!(::Array{Float64,2}, ::Array{Float64,2})`? If so, please edit that into your post, for completeness and searchability.

Comment: @phg a good point. Then `import Future: copy!` should work on Julia 1.0.1.

Comment: Yes, I am getting `MethodError: no method matching copy!(::Array{Float64,2}, ::Array{Float64,2})`. `V[1] .= V1` works well. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.=`:

```
V = ntuple(x -> zeros(5, 5), 2)
V1 = rand(5,5)
V[1] .= V1
```

It will make a copy of the values of `V1` in `V[1]`.